# Parse a string quoted by " in rust using lalrpop

Tags: parsing, rust

How to parse a string quoted by " in rust using lalrpop?

```rust
Str: Vec<u8> = {
    "\"" <s:r"([^\"])*"> "\"" => {
        s.bytes().collect()
    },
};
```

This doesn't work and I tried putting `\` at different places but haven't figured it out since there isn't much about regex in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lalrpop's [documentation](https://lalrpop.github.io/lalrpop/tutorial/002_paren_numbers.html) talks about this specifically:

> you can use hashes if you need to embed quotes, like `r#"..."..."#`.

In rust, `r"..."` is a [raw string](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#raw-string-literals), meaning all non-quote characters are taken literally, including `\`. There is no escape character for raw strings, but when you put `r#"` instead of `r"` at the beginning, the string won't end until it finds `"#`. You can do this with any number of `#` characters, so these are all the same string.

```rs
"hello"
r"hello"
r#"hello"#
r##"hello"##
r###"hello"###
```

And so on. This allows you to escape any `"` followed by any number of `#` with sufficient surrounding `#` symbols.

All that is a little overkill for this (and most things). For your regex, you just need one set of surrounding `#`, as the documentation shows, which looks like this.

```rs
r#"([^"])*"#
```

However, if you wanted a regex that excluded `"` and `#`, you could do:

```rs
r##"([^"#])*"##
```

Note that this is done because regexes often use lots of `\`, which would make escaping it annoying. You can also put a normal string with an escaped quote (at least in rust, I haven't tried it with lalrpop).

```rs
"([^\"])*"
```